# Which license for open source API with proprietary use of that API?

Tags: license-recommendation

What open source license do I use to also enable proprietary development using my open source library? I don't want to force all the proprietary source code to be free and available.

I'm building a wrapper over a commercial proprietary application's (CA) RestAPI in C#. I'm interested to put that wrapper into the public domain, and maybe open source it. My hope is that will promote use of the CA. I'll be making use of that wrapper in my own admin application, and that admin app will likely be free for individuals, but paid for commercial use and be proprietary.

Follow up - is there a community for micro-dev companies, one man band operations doing it for love and beer money?

Comment: Do you own all the code? The two ways you could go are the "dual licensing" route (if you own all the code), or else use a "permissive" license (search the site for both of these topics for more information).

Comment: @Brandin you know, if you felt like doing the two searches and providing a couple of pointers, that's basically the answer.  I urge you to write it up, so you can benefit from the upvotes.

Comment: You are confusing commercial and propitiatory: All Free Software and Open Source licences allow Commercial use. It looks like you are looking for licences that allow inclusion of a Free Software library into proprietary works. Is that correct?

Comment: Followup: one question per question (you can ask as many as you like).

Comment: Please read the Free Software definition https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html (it is like the Open Source definition, but easier to understand), it will help with your miss-conceptions.